# how to make two <li>s in separate <div><ul>s connectable with lines

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Sorry if the question is confusing.. I tried my best to describe the issue...

So, I'm trying to create a matching question for my students.
so the page would have a ul in 2 separate divs. I need a way to allow the students to click the li and connect to the matching li in the other div.

Comment: Can you be more clear about what you mean by "connect"?

Comment: i would like a line to display.

Answer (score 0):

You could allow them to drag from one list into the other list and instead of drawing a line, you could add a border of the same color to each paired element if they match or are correct.

Check out jQueryUI:

- http://jqueryui.com/draggable/
- http://jqueryui.com/droppable/

You could also have a `<canvas>` between the two lists and draw simple lines where the start and end of each line has appropriate x,y coordinates to aim at the respective `li` elements:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/canvas_drawing_lines.htm